# Building a numerical simulation of curvature flows. Where to start?

Tags: simulation, mean-curvature-flows

I would like to simulate the evolution of surfaces under various different curvature flows e.g. mean and gauss among others.

There are many different computer-graphics softwares which support visualisation and modelling with meshes (e.g. blender, various python packages ect.. ). I do not really know where to start, or whether any of these softwares will allow me to build the type of simulations I would like to run.

I have a background in Mathematics and have ran basic simulations before using Python. I have considered just building the simulation from the ground up myself, however I am unsure if what I am trying to do could be achieved much more quickly (and more efficiently) by using a pre-made framework such as blender ect..

It seems to me that the standard approach is to perform the simulation on a discrete mesh which approximates the surface you wish to flow. The curvature of the mesh can then be computed (via the tools of discrete differential geometry) and the position of the vertices modified in accordance to the curvature of the mesh at the vertex position.

If anyone knowledgeable in this area could provide me with some advice on this topic I'd be very grateful.